# Does MTCNN used in face alignment work well for other object detection task, like license plate?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

It has been proved that mtcnn works very well on face alignment task. Since face alignment can be count as a special object detection task, so I wonder whether mtcnn would perform well on other object detection task (for instance license plate detection).

I have googled around for use case of mtcnn used for other object detection task, but found very limited info.

Is mtcnn just not right for other object detection task, or there are other networks（like fast-rcnn, darknet19 used by yolo） can out perform mtcnn in every aspect of object detection task?

Comment: It's hard to answer this kind of questions. The performance of a network may vary - and significantly - with the same task and a different dataset. For example, SSD's performance is worse on the same as PASCAL VOC 21 classes, different dataset - that contains smaller objects (relative to the whole picture). In this case it is understood why, but in other cases such understanding requires thorough analysis.

Comment: but it seams that there has been no one even trying to use mtcnn for other object detection task. So I just want to know that whether mtcnn is theoretically not suitable for other object detection task or not. If so, I may just forget about mtcnn in my following experiments and save some time...

Comment: My guess is that it's just like many many other domain specific (face, in your case) detection networks which weren't adopted to other domains. There are hundreds if not thousands of detection networks, and obviously not all of them are widely used. fast(er) rcnn, yolo and ssd caught a lot of attention and became a kind of state of the art because of accuracy/ runtime / tradeoff between these two; you can still find many many others that may even suppress the known architectures, but only didn't get enough attention and "buzz". Again, you can't tell in advance how it'll perform w/o trying.